# About limiting the number of file descriptors

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, ulimit

I have a question about limiting FD(file descriptors):

when I am using "ulimit -n 1000000", it means that the program is allowed to use at most 1000000 FD resources,

However, "cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max" shows that 803766 FDs are available in total, which is smaller than 1000000.

So, what's the number of FD on earch that the program is able to use, 1000000 or 803766?

Comment: getrlimit(), setrlimit(), and check the return value!  RLIMIT_NOFILE is what you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/sys/fs/file-max` takes precedence over any ulimit settings in the shell.

More over `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` is the total number of FD open for ALL processes on given machine.

`ulimit` settings are per process, so any new process started will have given limit (unless the total form `file-max` is exceeded in the system).

Comment: So do you mean that it's useless if ulimit set the value larger than the value from /proc/sys/fs/file-max ?

Comment: is there any other config which sets the limit ?